# Synonyms for 'from what time'

Tags: phrase-request, questions, time-words

I, normally, use 'from what time' and 'how long' to ask someone (e.g. a seller) something like

```
from what time did you open the store, today?
How long is your shop is open today?
```

But I don't know if 'from what time' is usual or no. I think that 'since when' is sometimes used when I have a complaint and say for example

```
Since when did you have the right to get my father's book?
```

Tell me please if 'from what time' is a usual phrase to ask such things.

Comment: How long since has the shop been open?

Answer (score 2):

The following are idiomatic:

> When did you open the shop today?
>
> At what time did you open the shop today?
>
> When does the shop open?
>
> At what time does the shop open?

Comment: Yes, I use it sometimes; but to ask when the time of coming is important for me; but by the above questions I would like to know how long they have been here.

Comment: If at noon you ask "How long has the shop been open today?" and you receive the reply "four hours", you would know that the shop opened at 8AM.

Comment: Yes, but you know that language usage is completely focus-sensitive. sometimes I focus on the beginning time and sometimes on the interval, though the answers are convertible.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I would like to know how long they have been here". Your question is a moving target.

Comment: "Since what time have you been open today?" would receive a time of day in response, but it is an awkward way to ask, compared to "What time did you open today?" or "At what time did you open today?"